# Не могу разобраться с импортированием в Golang

Tags: golang

Расскажите, расставьте по полочкам принцип импортирования сторонних пакетов в мельчайших подробностях, включая `go get` и переменные `GOROOT`, `GOPATH`. Можете написать пошагово как ***вы*** импортируете сторонние библиотеки. Или я создаю неправильную структуру проекта(в некоторых статьях видел в корневой директории поддиректории `bin`, `src`, `pkg`) и что внутри `src` тоже соблюдается какая-то особая структура.

А то я пишу проект, а он у меня просто не собирается и во время написания кода падают ошибки импорта сторонних пакетов. И это уже не первый такой проект. Мне это уже надоело. Ни одна статья мне не рассказала как делать действительно правильно.

Comment: [*How to write Go code*](https://golang.org/doc/code.html), [*GOPATH*](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть отличная статья
https://habr.com/ru/post/249545/
Если кратко в Unix системах регистрируешь переменную GOPATH и прописываешь ее в файл своего профиля

```
echo "export GOPATH=~/go" >> ~/.profile
```

Для windows настраиваешь эту переменную

```
+«Панель управления» 
+«Система и безопасность» 
+«Система»
+«Расширенные настройки системы»
+«Переменные среды»
```

(Вместо go можно дать любое наименование директории, например go_works.
И не путай эту директорию с директорией установки самого go)

Твой домашний каталог для проектов будет иметь структуру

```
  go_works
       bin
       pkg
       src
```

если теперь, выполнить установку пакета github.com/gorilla/mux, например так

```
cd $GOPATH
go get github.com/gorilla/mux
```

в твою структуру каталогов развернется этот пакет и будет доступен для import`а в твоих проектах.
Свои проекты располагай в каталоге src, или если имеешь учетку you-name на github.com то структура каталогов проектов должна быть такой

```
go_works 
    src/github.com/you-name/you-project1/main.go
    src/github.com/you-name/you-project2/main.go
```

сам на этом споткнулся :)

Comment: Спасибо. То, что нужно.